# Using breadth first or depth first to separate connected components

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

[image]

1. I have a data set that gave me the following picture that I have attached.Each node represents a cluster and the number inside the node represents the number of points in that cluster.
2. I also wrote a code to trace back those points. As an example lets say I want to know which points out of all data, gives me the RED node with 46 points.I was able to find out.
3. Here is where the problem starts. Suppose I have 2 nodes with 24 points in each. How can I know which points represents the red and the blue.(Like in the picture). Of course I can cross check the adjacent nodes and check for similar points. But I want a code to that. Basically I want to separate the connected components based on their adjacent nodes.
4. So how can I separate these connected components using depth first or breadth-first search?
5. I have been investigating breadthfirst and depth first search but I dont know how to do it. I am new to Matlab can someone help me.

Comment: What do the links represent ? Also without a minimal code it's hard to answer.

Comment: The links(edges) represent that the nodes have points in common. I have an Adjacency matrix made already. Just need to go from there to separate the connected components.The code is too big to put here. @Ratbert